# Images without borders in PropertyGrid control

Tags: winforms, image, windows-forms-designer, propertygrid

Using windows forms PropertyGrid control I can add images into select for any property using some UI type converters, etc. This control adds black border for each picture in the list. Does anybody know how to remove it?

See the samples of desired and existing picture here

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Post the custom `UITypeEditor` code you are using to draw the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following line of code in your custom `UITypeEditor` class before drawing the image:

```
e.Graphics.ExcludeClip(e.Bounds);
```

Comment: when I exclude a clip, like this, nothing is rendered in the bounds, how is that ? so when the whole rectangle is excluded, how can we draw in it ?

Comment: My answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512018/propertygrid-paintvalue-issue-how-to-remove-and-paint-outside-the-standard-re removes only the rectangle borders.